# Use getText().toString(); As Database Query Filter

Tags: android, sqlite

I am just learning about Android and databases and would appreciate some assistance, hope I can be clear.

I have an Activity class where I get the getText().toString() value which works fine when I log the value returned, I would like to take this value and use it in my DatabaseHelper class to filter my query by this value which comes from a user click.

Activity Class:

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) viewClicked;                            
    TextView tv = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.textViewArtistsSingle); 
    String tvName = tv.getText().toString()     

    // tv.getText().toString() will return JOHN if the user clicked on John

    startActivity(new Intent(CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this, NEXT_ACTIVITY.class));
```

DatabaseHelper Class:

```
    public List<String> getDBNameSingle(){

    List<String> listRows = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c;

    try {

        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM " + TABLE_LM + " WHERE name = 'JOHN'", null); //Get Specific Name HARD)
```

I would like to HAVE THIS: (note tvName from getText().toString()

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM " + TABLE_LM + " WHERE name = '" + tvName +"'", null); //Get Specific Name VARIABLE)
```

INSTEAD of THIS:

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM " + TABLE_LM + " WHERE name = 'JOHN'", null); //Get Specific Name HARD)
```

But my DatabaseHelper class does not know about tvName, how can I pass this variable from CURRENT_ACTIVITY to DatabaseHelper so that I may filter the name column to return the row WHERE name = tvName (from getText().toString();)

Comment: Change the signature of your `getDBNameSingle()` method to be `public List<String> getDBNameSingle(String name)` and simply pass the name into it when you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I pass this variable from CURRENT_ACTIVITY to DatabaseHelper

Before passing `tvName` to `DatabaseHelper` need to get `tvName`  in `NEXT_ACTIVITY` class:

**1.** Use `Intent.putExtra` for sending `tvName`  String value to `NEXT_ACTIVITY` from `CURRENT_ACTIVITY` on `ListView` row click.

**2.** Get `tvName`  String value in `onCreate` method  from Intent which is obtained using `getIntent()` in `NEXT_ACTIVITY`.

**3.** To get `tvName`  variable value in `DatabaseHelper` add String parameter to  `getDBNameSingle` method:

```
  public List<String> getDBNameSingle(String strName){
    // Use strName for passing selected name in query
    ....
  }
```

Comment: I'm interested in point number 3. Can you provide more info please, how do I use strName to pass selected name in query, all I want is for the SQL class to know tvName so if you could elaborate more on point 3 please

Comment: @TwoStarII: `I'm interested in point number 3` to get value in SQL class you must send if from `CURRENT_ACTIVITY` to `NEXT_ACTIVITY`  then send to `DatabaseHelper` class

Comment: @TwoStarII: As i understand you have ListView in `CURRENT_ACTIVITY`  , starting `NEXT_ACTIVITY` on ListView Item Click, Calling `getDBNameSingle` method from `DatabaseHelper` class in  `NEXT_ACTIVITY` Activity. i am right?

Comment: Yes, but at this point I think NEXT_ACTIVITY is irrelevant at the moment, I just need to work with CURRENT_ACTIVITY and DatabaseHelpler so that the rawQuery uses tvName to filter by name

Comment: @TwoStarII: then pass `tvName` in `getDBNameSingle` method like `getDBNameSingle(tvName)`

Comment: @TwoStarII: In which line getting `tvName cannot be resolved to a type` error?

Comment: public List<String> getDBNameSingle(tvName){

Comment: @TwoStarII: Use `public List<String> getDBNameSingle(String tvName){`

Comment: Allow me a moment to fix my app, I have uninstalled the app then reinstalled it so that the DB can update but it is not being copied, the app only reads one table which is android_metadata, I have no idea why it is doing this now so I'm trying to fix that quickly.

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K: Finally fixed my database copy isue, now back to your possible solution, when I add the String tvName in getDBNameSingle from DatabaseHelper class I have to add an argument in arrArtist = dbHeplper.getDBNameSingle(); from CURRENT_ACTIVITY so that it matches the argument from DatabaseHelper class otherwise error returned is:

The method getDBNameSingle(String) in the type DatabaseHelper is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: @TwoStarII: answer help u or not in fixing posted issue?